# What's the best way to use a prop to dynamically name a div id and button data-bs-target in Vue.js and Bootstrap 5?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, carousel, bootstrap-5

How to name a div id with a parameter passed as props

I am trying to name the id of a div and the data-bs-target of a button with a name passed as props so that I can use the same component multiple times on the same page with different identifiers.
Because they are buttons and with a general identifier even if I press different buttons, the first button is always pressed, because they all have the same identifier.

Class RestauranteCard.vue
HTML

```
      <div
          v-if="!noimage"
          id=carouselNumber
          class="carousel slide"
          data-bs-ride="carousel"
          data-interval="false"
      >
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div
              v-for="(link, idx) in imagenesLink"
              :key="link"
              class="carousel-item"
              :class="{ active: idx === 0 }"
          >
            <img :src="link" class="d-block w-100" alt="foto" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <button
            class="carousel-control-prev"
            type="button"
            data-bs-target=#carouselNumber
            data-bs-slide="prev"
        >
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button
            class="carousel-control-next"
            type="button"
            data-bs-target=#carouselNumber
            data-bs-slide="next"
        >
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
```

JS

```
  props: {
    restaurante: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
    carouselNumber: {
      type: String
    }
  },
```

The class calling RestaurantCard

```
      <div v-else
          class="card row-cols-1"
          v-for="restaurante in restaurantes"
          :key="restaurante.id"
      >
        <RestauranteCard :restaurante="restaurante" :carouselNumber="restaurante.id"></RestauranteCard>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `id` is a fallthrough attribute which is passed implicitly without need to define it as prop, you can do :

```html
  <div v-else
          class="card row-cols-1"
          v-for="restaurante in restaurantes"
          :key="restaurante.id"
      >
        <RestauranteCard  :id="restaurante.id" :restaurante="restaurante" :carouselNumber="restaurante.id"></RestauranteCard>
      </div>
```